# How to make View not movable

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uiwebview

I am having trouble removing what I think is the margin, padding or scroll from the `xamarin.ios` framework. As you can see from the gif below, when I scroll up or down the whole view seems to move. How can I prevent the user from being able to scroll the `UIWebView` element (if that is what causes the problem) away?

[image: Visual representation]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following code

```
 webView.ScrollView.Bounces = false;
```

Comment: Thanks! How can I change the color of the gray borders (un-safearea)?

Comment: webView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;

Comment: do you have any experience with [Loading local file to WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57093070) ?

Comment: You can check it now .