# Why is NSBundle.MainBundle.GetUrlForResource returning null

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uiwebview

I am using UIWebView to view a local HTML file. My file is named *NoWiFi.html* and has the following path Resources/NoWiFi.html. I have also set the Build Action to BundleResource, and tried:

```
string name = "Resources/NoWiFI.html"
NSURl url;

url = new NSUrl(Path.Combine(NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath, name), false);
// and
url = NSBundle.MainBundle.GetUrlForResource("NoWiFi", "html"); // returns null 

webView.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(url));
```

as in the [xamarins documentation](https://github.com/xamarin/docs-archive/tree/master/Recipes/ios/content_controls/web_view/load_local_content)
but then i get an error: *The requested URL was not found on this server*

Why does not my code find the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some wired reason my problem solved it self once i renamed the file, if anyone else is tying to load a local HTML file my code looks like this:

```
NSUrl url = NSBundle.MainBundle.GetUrlForResource("NoWiFi", "html");
webView.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(url));
```

And if your url object is null when you are inspecting it with the debugger make sure the local file (in my case NoWiFi.html) has Build Action set to: BundleResource and if the NSUrl object is still null, try renaming the file

Comment: just out of curiosity, did you rename file in solution explorer or finder? Most likely it was just changing the Build Action to BundleResource and doing a clean and rebuild that solved your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Because you load local html file .So you should use

```
webView.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(url),false);
```

**isDir**：A Boolean value that specifies whether path is treated as a directory path when resolving against relative path components. Pass True if the path indicates a directory, False otherwise.

Comment: It looks like my LoadRequest does not have a overload that takes 2 arguments

Comment: Can you share a sample which contains the issue so that I can  test it on my side .Don't forget to remove your personal info.

Comment: I believe [these](https://repl.it/repls/RunnyUnusualWebsphere) are all the essential files

Comment: It seems that your demo contains your url . You should remove them  or replace it as xxx .

Comment: yeah I realized it has been removed

Comment: I will check it .

Comment: I managed to fix the issue, not completely sure what the issue was but it works, thanks for all the help!